# Как сделать боковое маленькое активити(или как это назвать)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пишу свой калькулятор и хочу сделать боковое меню, которое открывалось бы свайпом или нажатием на кнопку(скрин, справа слева такая кнопка, более темного фиолетового цвета), но не совсем понимаю, как это можно реализовать...
Подскажите пожалуйста
[image: До открытия панели]

[image: Открытая панель]

Answer (score 1):

Для решения Вашей задачи скорее всего подойдёт [Navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#add_a_navigation_drawer).

Comment: Да, возможно вы правы, но при открытии drawer layout остальная часть программы становится недоступной, в том числе и TextView.Как это исправить?